# for-case loop evaluates second iteration twice and skips third iteration

Tags: python

So i have this code:

```
def Convert(ama,a):
    print ama,a

def run():
    z=0
    while z!=3:
        z+=1

        if z==1:
            n='e'
        if z==2:
            n='B'
        if z=='3':
            n='G'

        a='-----2-----5-6----7'
        Convert(a,n)
run()
```

The result:

```
-----2-----5-6----7 e
-----2-----5-6----7 B
-----2-----5-6----7 B
```

Although the result I expected was:

```
-----2-----5-6----7 e
-----2-----5-6----7 B
-----2-----5-6----7 G
```

Please help.

Comment: The program outputs four lines, not the three you show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    if z=='3':
```

should be this

```
    if z==3:
```

Comment: Specifically, `'3'` is a `str` while `3` is an `int`. In Python they aren't the same.